# $f\left(x + \frac1x\right)= x^3+x^{-3},$ find $f(x)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

$$f\left(x + \frac1x\right)= x^3+x^{-3},$$ find $f(x)$.

What i do know at this state is that..

express x as a function of y :

$y= x + 1/x$

$x^2−xy+1=0$

Quad formula: 
$x= (y ± \sqrt {y^2-4}) / 2$

When i substitute this into the original equation, i can't solve it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: is it $f\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)$?

Comment: Hind - how can you write $x^{-3}$ in other way?

Comment: I think this a duplicate from a couple of years ago, answered by either Lab or Sami.

Answer (score 8):

There is a pretty straightforward answer. Polynomials are very strict in what terms they allow. Why not try matching the first part $x^3$? What would you have to do with the term $x+\frac{1}{x}$ to get $x^3$ as a first term? Then look at your result and try to remove whatever there is too much, again in terms of $x+\frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 5):

$x^3+x^{-3}=(x + \frac{1}{x})^3-3(x + \frac{1}{x})$

set $t=x + \frac{1}{x}, f(t)= t^3-3t$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
f\left(x + \frac1x\right)= x^3+x^{-3}
$$
$$
\left(x + \frac1x\right)^3 = x^3 + 3x + 3\frac1x+x^{-3}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow f(t) = t^3 - 3t
$$

Answer (score 2):

As $\left|x+  \frac 1x\right| \ge 2$,  $f$ is only constrained of $\{y :|y|\ge 2  \}$.
$$ x + \frac 1x = y 
\\ x^2 - xy + 1  = 0
\\ x = \frac12\left(
y \pm \sqrt{y^2 - 4}
\right)
$$
Hence on this set:
$$f(y) = \frac 18\left(y + \sqrt{y^2 - 4}\right)^3 + 
8\left(y + \sqrt{y^2 - 4}\right)^{-3}
$$

When you expand the formula, it turns out that 
$$
f(y) = \begin{cases}y^3 - 3y &\text{ when }x\in(-\infty,-2]\cup [2,\infty) \\
\text{anything} &\text{ when }x\in(-2,2)
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: If you do the algebra, it turns out that this gives $f(y) = y^3 - 3y$, agreeing with the answer many others have given.

Comment: @MichaelLugo most other answers just check that this is a solution. And do not address the issue of the interval $[-2,2]$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe
$$f(x):=x^3-3x$$

Thus
$$f(x+x^{-1})=x^3+3x+3x^{-1}+x^{-3}-3x-3x^{-1}=x^3+x^{-3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\left(x + \frac1x\right)^3=x^3+3x^2\frac1x+3x\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, $x+1/x = 2 \cosh( \log (x))$ so what you have is also $$f(2 \cosh(\log(x))) = 2\cosh(3\log(x)) $$ 
Perhaps you can then continue on your own...